# Problems creating a relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having trouble getting my relations to work with doctrine2.

The Error message is the following when generating the schema:

`"The table with name 'wasd.user_post' already exists."`

My problem is that i don't understand what relations are causing this error message to appear.

These are my entities:

Post:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="posts")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="text")
     */
    private $text;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="votes", type="integer")
     */
    private $votes = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="posts")
     */
    private $owner;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="upvotedPosts")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="post_upvotes")
     */
    private $upvotedBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="downvotedPosts")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="post_downvotes")
     */
    private $downvotedBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="post")
     */
    private $comments;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Attachment", mappedBy="post")
     */
    private $attachments;

}
```

User:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_summoner_verified", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isSummonerVerified = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="summoner_id", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $summonerId = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="summoner_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $summonerName = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="display_league", type="boolean")
     */
    private $displayLeague = true;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="display_summoner", type="boolean")
     */
    private $displaySummoner = true;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="league", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $league = '';

    /**
     * @var $posts
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="owner")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id")
     */
    private $posts;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="summoner_verify_code", type="string", length=8)
     */
    private $summonerVerifyCode = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="upvotedBy")
     */
    private $upvotedPosts;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="downvotedBy")
     */
    private $downvotedPosts;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Comment", inversedBy="upvotedBy")
     */
    private $upvotedComments;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Comment", inversedBy="downvotedBy")
     */
    private $downvotedComments;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Stream", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $stream = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $comments;

}
```

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that you have orm files under Resources/config/doctrine

Comment: Sadly no, but thanks :)

Comment: Ok. Looks like you are trying to create two ManyToMany relations between User and Post.  By default they will both try to use a table called user_post.  So you might consider adding a @JoinTable parameter. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional

Comment: Yeah, i've tried that on the Post entity (see question), did i use it wrong? To me it looks exactly like in example 6.9 from the docs

Comment: I found the problem, i was using invseredBy 2x instead of mappedBy & inversedBy